# Unity Built Application Crashes on Startup

Tags: unity-game-engine

My Unity Built Application crashes on startup but it runs perfectly on the game view simulator. It also runs perfectly When built as a web player in offline deployment the only error i get witch normally results in a texture not appearing when its built but that dosent happen is this:

Missing Detail texture in Terrain, degraded loading performance.

I have no idea whats going on. Im not a pro at unity but im not a newbie either Thanks In advance.

This is my first post, By the way.

Comment: Some more logs or any other information that we can help you?

Comment: *Fixed* it was a player Setting that i just messed around with until it worked

Comment: Perfect, glad to hear this. Could you just drop a note what went wrong and how to fix it as answer to your own question so that others could find the solution as well? Feel safe to get my 10 points and welcome to the club of supporters :)

Comment: @daboss42 I agree with Kay, you should explain in details how was your fix and actually do it as your own answer. You then you can mark it as the correct answer and people like me who are digging for Unanswered question will not spend useless time here :) Regards

Comment: Kay and @ForceMagic, how about adding a TAG to these kinds of question where the question isn't clear and/or the OP just doesn't give a damn? I'd call it **[abandoned]**

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else who hits this issue: Often I've hit this problem where running via the debugger on Android works fine, but running via the installed APK does not.

In this case, the best technique is to run the application on your Android but use Android Studio to connect logcat to your android.  When the process crashes, logcat will capture the stacktrace, which will give you a clue what to look for.